# Is it possible to filter an RTK Kanji Anki deck to only include Kanji from a vocab deck?

Tags: vocabulary, anki, japanese, kanji

Is this an appropriate place to ask about setting up Anki?

I have used RTK (Remembering the Kanji) in the past, and it was helpful for kanji recall using the little mnemonics, but I wasn't really learning any vocabulary. It's been a while, and now I'm trying to hit it from another angle, learning vocab as I find them in Manga. Sometimes I find a pre-made Anki deck for a manga issue which is nice. I find this to be much better for learning to read, but I only really retain it if I also practice writing.

I'm wondering if it's possible to filter an RTK deck to only include the Kanji from my separate vocab list deck, so I'm not just learning random Kanji, but supplementing the study of vocabulary from the pages I'm actually reading.